# How to create my own virtual machine base images?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, virtualbox, libvirt, qemu

I would like to create my own base VM image to allow for faster provisioning of new VMs.

Right now, I'm creating a new and empty VM, inserting the distribution's ISO into it, and going through the whole installer. It takes me 20-30 minutes just to have a fresh machine installed.

Is it a matter of creating and installing the VM manually, and then once it's setup using the `libvirt` tools to delete the MAC address, change hostname, etc? Or is there a better way to do it?

I'm using KVM/QEMU if that makes a difference, but I'd like to create base images that are vendor agnostic so the same image can run in VirtualBox etc.

Comment: This is a great question, I wish you people didn't brush it off as off topic. The question reflects the lack of good documentation to perform a task that I am facing now too. Thanks a lot.